# How can I reach swing elements from a listener?

Tags: java, swing, class, listener, implementation

I am currently learning how to use ActionListeners and I have a few questions about how it should be done.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    frame.setSize(250,250);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    final JTextField text1 = new JTextField(" ",10);
    final JTextField text2 = new JTextField(" ",10);
    final JTextField text3 = new JTextField(" ",10);
    final JTextField text4 = new JTextField(" ",10);
    panel.add(text1);
    panel.add(text2);
    panel.add(text3);
    panel.add(text4);

    ActionListener a = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        text4.setText(text1.getText()+""+text2.getText()+""+text3.getText());
        }
    };


    JButton buton = new JButton("Go");
    buton.addActionListener(a);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(buton);
    frame.revalidate();
}
```

Given the code in the example, that is the only method I use inside my main class.  As you can see for the listeners I am currently using some anonymous listeners that are implemented inside my main(). The thing is... I use them because clicking a button in the frame actually needs to change the content of another element. 
My question is : Can you make the listener non-anonymous while still being able to use the other components? What I am thinking is moving the ActionListener implementation for the button in another class, but then how do I reach the properties of the other elements?
Example :

```
  class listener implements ActionListener{
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     text4.setText(text1.getText()+""+text2.getText()+""+text3.getText());
     }
  }
```

then in my main() class I want to simply call :

```
 listener l = new listener();
 buton.addActionListener();
```

And still be able to make this outside listener acces properties of the elements inside the main class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But you'll need to explicitely pass the components to the listener, instead of passing them implicitely to the anonyous class:

```
class MyListener implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField text1;
    private JTextField text2;
    private JTextField text3;
    private JTextField text4;

    public MyListener(JTextField text1, JTextField text2, JTextField text3, JTextField text4) {
        this.text1 = text1;
        this.text2 = text2;
        this.text3 = text3;
        this.text4 = text4;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        text4.setText(text1.getText()+""+text2.getText()+""+text3.getText());
    }
}
```

And in the main method:

```
button.addActionListener(new MyActionListener(text1, text2, text3, text4);
```

Usually though, components are stored in instance variables of an object (subclass of JPanel, typically), and listeners are implemented as inner classes (anonymous or not) that can thus access the instance variables directly:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton button;

    public MyPanel() {
        // ...
        button.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
    }

    private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(textField.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Also, note that:

- you should not access swing components from the main thread. Only from the EDT. Read the [swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).
- you should call `pack()` and `setVisible()` *after* the components have been added. `revalidate()` is useless in this case. Don't call `setSize()`. It's the role of the layout manager and of the `pack()` method to find the appropriate dimension of the frame.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. The listener info you have provided is quite helpful. Regarding the swing usage in the main thread I will look into it, but the example I gave is simply a thing of convenience through my learning process.